# XML replace empty space with value

Tags: python, xml

I have the problem to get the value empty spaces. I want to replace the `type="open"/>` with value of `testvalue="0"` and change the type:

```
        <test testvalue="0">Something3</test>
        <test testvalue="1" type="done">Hallo2</test>
        <test testvalue="2" type="done">Hallo2</test>
        <test testvalue="3" type="open"/>
        <test testvalue="4" type="open"/>
```

Results should be like:

```
        <test testvalue="0">Something</test>
        <test testvalue="1" type="done">Hallo</test>
        <test testvalue="2" type="done">Hallo</test>
        <test testvalue="3" type="done">Something</test>
        <test testvalue="4" type="done">Something</test>
```

Is there a possible way to do it by searching for the `testvalue="0"` get the value and replace the `type="open"/>` with `type="done">"(0 value)</test>`.

Comment: There are some good libraries for parsing XML in Python, you could take a look [here](/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python). Once you have it parsed then you can figure out how to set values and rewrite it as an XML file.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan IMVHO you should move your comment to answer, it's good.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using System.XML and have a way of reading 
the XML file. You would need to specify the Node test such as

```
'XmlNodeList testValues = new XmlNodeList("/test");'
```

this will return all your test Nodes in a list.
then select the ones you want to overwrite by doing

```
 'testValues[numberOfNodeInList].InnerText = "What you want to put here ";'
```

Note: You must initialize the XML doc u want to read, with

```
   'XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();'
   'xml.load(path)'
```

And then you can get the node like I mentioned using XmlNodeList or XmlNode.
Refer to this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml(v=vs.110).aspx
to see all you can do with system.xml;

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use an XML parser, thankfully [Python has one built in](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

You first need to import it, then parse your file by passing the path of it to the parser. Note that you *need* a root tag to make this valid XML for the parser. Otherwise you'll get the error:

```
ParseError: junk after document element: line 2, column 8
```

It's easy to modify your data however, just add a `root` tag at the start and end. This could be done programmatically if necessary.

```
<root>
        <test testvalue="0">Something3</test>
        <test testvalue="1" type="done">Hallo2</test>
        <test testvalue="2" type="done">Hallo2</test>
        <test testvalue="3" type="open"/>
        <test testvalue="4" type="open"/>
</root>
```

Now you can parse it easily with the parser:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ETree
xml = ETree.parse(path)
```

And then you can iterate over the XML, detecting if `element.text is None` and write it to a path:

```
for element in xml.getroot():
    if element.text is None:
        element.text = "Something"
xml.write(path)
```